# Какие нужны критерии и требования для создании службы Windows?

Tags: windows, golang, service, ос

Какие требования нужны для создании службы Windows? 
Как не пытаюсь создать всегда одна и та же проблема: `Error 1053: "The service did not respond in a timely fashion" when attempting to start, stop or pause a service`. Как я знаю есть специальный критерии и требования для службы допустим чтоб службу можно было остановить, а не убивать процесс и т.д. Какие именно нужны критерии и есть ли реализации на ЯП `Golang`? 
**Код:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "github.com/takama/daemon"
)

func main() {
    service, err := daemon.New("name", "description")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Error: ", err)
    }
    status, err := service.Install()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(status, "\nError: ", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(status)
}
```

Реализует установку службы (запуск можно делать через sc.exe или же через фукнцию run)
Но как запустить я не знаю, может с бубнами потанцевать или пошаманить..

Comment: Не буду говорить за goland, но сам запуск службы происходит в контексте SC. За какое-то отведенное время необходимо создать Callback для реагирования на события от SC и обновить свой статус (Например на "запущенный"). Если за отведенное время ничего из этого не произошло, то timeout и служба не отвечает. Это так работает в WinAPI.

Answer (score 0):

> Error 1053: "The service did not respond in a timely fashion" when attempting to start, stop or pause a service

Это сообщение говорит о том, что дело не в том, как вы запускаете сервис, а в том, что Windows считает, что он некорректно работает.
Если сервис все время активен, то ОС полагает, что сервис не дает работать никакому другому ПО и значит он только мешает и его надо установить. Если сервис не работает, то ОС считает, что он впустую занимает ресурсы системы и его надо остановить. Вот надо попасть между этими двумя альтенативами, типа то работает, то не работает. Например, установить таймер со срабатывающим событием раз в минуту. И это просто помимо основной работы сервера.

Answer (score 0):

takama/daemon под Windows не работает, по крайней мере стандартный пример. 
Используйте штатный пакет https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys/windows/svc, там пример рабочий.